# Passing zsh command line arguments into xargs quotations

Tags: zsh, xargs

I have a zsh function, fvi (find vi), which recursively greps a directory searching for files with a pattern, collects them and opens them in vim (on the Mac):

```
function fvi { grep -rl $1 . | xargs sh -c '/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g -- "$@" <$0' /dev/tty }
```

This looks bad but works fine (on the Mac). But I'd like to set the search pattern for vi to *$1* with:

```
function fvi { grep -rl $1 . | xargs zsh -c '/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -c +/"$1" -g -- "$@" <$0' /dev/tty }
```

This of course does not work since xargs/zsh sees the $1 and translates it into a file name. I can manually say -c +/xyz and it will set the pattern to xyz. So I know the vim command syntax is working. I just can't get the shell command argument $1 to be substituted *into* the xargs string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just asking for vi to see a literal `$1`? Have you tried single quotes instead of double (i.e. `+/'$1'`) or escaping it (i.e. `+/"\$1"`)?

Comment: Nope. ', '', ", \ and \\ didn't work. What fvi hello currently does is to recursively search through the current directory for files with the string hello in them, collect that list and open all of them in vim. The above function does that.  What I want is all that AND to then open all those files with vim AND with -c +/hello.

Answer (score 0):

I might just use `find`:

```
fvi () {
    v=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
    find . -exec grep -e $1 -- {} \; -exec $v -g +/$1 -- {} \;
}
```

The fact that you are opening each file in `vim` for interactive editing suggests there are not so many possible matches (or candidates) that running `grep` multiple times is really an issue. (At worst, you are just replacing each extra shell process started by `xargs` with an instance of `grep`.)

This also precludes any possible issue regarding file names that contain a newline.

Comment: Thanks. However, that opens a Vim window for each matching file which is really uncomfortable if there are 50 matches. The xargs approach opens one window. Then I hit :n to flip to the next file.

Comment: At least this echos the right vim command:  function ffvi () {
    v="/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g -m -i NONE -c +/$1 -- " ;
    grep -rl $1 . | xargs -t zsh -c $v
}